# Laravel : Store full image path in database

Tags: laravel

I want to store my image upload path in table.Currently it returns

`/storage/images/user/business_card/1524811791.jpg"`

I want to store full access URL for example `abc.com/storage/images/user/business_card/1524811791.jpg`

How can i do this ?

Image Upload Code :

```
    if(Input::file('profile_picture'))
        {
            $profilepic = Input::file('profile_picture');
            $filename  = time() . '.' . $profilepic->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $request->file('profile_picture')->storeAs('public/images/user/profile', $filename);
            $accessUrl = Storage::url('images/user/profile'). '/' . $filename;
            $url = Storage::put('public/user/profile/', $filename);
            $saveUserInformation->profile_picture = $accessUrl;
            $saveUserInformation->save();
        }
```

Comment: [According to the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#file-urls) *If you are using the local driver, this will typically just prepend /storage to the given path and return a relative URL to the file. If you are using the s3 or rackspace driver, the fully qualified remote URL will be returned* therefore for the local driver you need to pretend `URL::base()` yourself

Comment: did you find solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all it is bad practice. Imagine a problem when your domain changes, then you need to make huge work in database. Therefore the relative path is better.

But If you realy need absolute path you can take domain:

```
{{ Request::root() }}
```

Or

```
{{ Request::server ("SERVER_NAME") }}
```

and add it before storage path.

Good luck!

Comment: plus one for suggestion.thanx

Comment: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50040436/laravel-how-can-i-validate-reset-password-table-token-and-request-token?noredirect=1#comment87097209_50040436` help me for this.

Comment: I will look at this

Comment: waiting for your response @Adam

Answer (score 1):

```
 $saveUserInformation->profile_picture = URL::to('/').$accessUrl;
```